# virt-clone - ignore that guest is running

Tags: kvm, libvirt

I am using the following command to generate the xml template for new guests that I create with overlay images that point to a backing file of the original guest (thinly provisioned clones):

```
virt-clone \
--original $ORIGINAL_GUEST \
--name $NEW_GUEST_NAME \
--file=$NEW_GUEST_OVERLAY_DISK \
--preserve-data \
--print-xml > $XML_FILE_FOR_NEW_GUEST
```

This works fine when the guest to be cloned is not running, but I get the following error message when it is running:

> ERROR    Domain with devices to clone must be paused or shutoff.

I can understand why this error message exists, because one normally runs the `virt-clone` command to actually clone a guest and so it needs to not be running, but I have specified `--print-xml` and no actual cloning is taking place so it shouldn't matter.

**Is there a way to prevent this error message stopping the command proceeding?**

The only alternative I can think of is to write a script that uses `virsh dumpxml` to grab the xml and then manually edit the necessary details, such as giving it the new name, a new mac address, and point to the the new overlay file (and probably other stuff that I haven't realised yet)?

### Context

- Ubuntu 16.04 running libvirt 1.3.1

Comment: Have you tried crossposting this on http://askubuntu.com/

Comment: You may `virsh dumpxml ... > <dumpfile>` the original domain and then use `virt-clone --original-xml <dumpfile> ...`. This does not need to connect to the virtual machine and works even when the original is running (see `man virt-clone`).

Comment: @ridgy wahey! that worked beautifully. Please can you post that as an answer and I will mark it correct.

Comment: @wogsland I tend not to cross-post as I believe that is shunned, so I just try to pick whichever one of these is most appropriate. I'll use askubuntu for whatever is specific to only ubuntu, but I think these KVM questions are most appropriate here as other distros probably have the same issue(s).